# how to use pivot value inside Eloquent in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

for example table1 and table2 and connected together by a pivot table

```
table1: {
    pivot: {
        pivot_value1: 1
    },
    table2: {
        ....    
    }
}
```

code:

```
table1::with(['table2' => function($q) {
    $q->where('table2_property1', 'pivot_value1') // <= how to access pivot value?
}])
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) under 'Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns' section.

Comment: Means , you are trying to get the column's values from pivot table?

Comment: I mean using multi condition joining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model where you are defining relationship , we need to use `withPivot()` function while making relationship e.g in your table1 Model we have;

```
class Table1 {
       public function table2() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Table2')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
      }
}
```

Normally in pivot table there are three cloumns, in addition if we have added extra columns let's say column1 & column2, we can get the values of these extra cloumns. Here column1 & column2 are the extras columns in your pivot tables, 
To access these columns values:

```
    $table1 = Table1::find(1);

     foreach ($table1->table2 as $table) {
      echo $table->pivot->column1;
      echo $table->pivot->column2;
     }
```

Another Solution using query builder:

```
Table1::whereHas('table2', function($q) {
    $q->where('table2_property1', 'pivot_value1');
})
->get();
```

The above code is just an example, you can do modify it that perfect your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: How can i access pivot value inside the query itself?

Comment: whereHas filters Table1 but I am trying to filter Table2

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is select * from table1, pivot, table2 where table1.id = pivot.table1_id and pivot.table2_id = table2.id and pivot.version = table2.version